# How to send parameters to the started application java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am trying to develop simple standalone java app. I am using jetty.

Starting embedded server:

```
String WEBAPPDIR = "web/";
Server server = new Server(8080);
String CONTEXTPATH = "/";
Server.setHandler(new WebAppContext(WEBAPPDIR, CONTEXTPATH));
server.start();
```

**How i can put/send parameters to this app, which is launched at this moment, from external environment (for example, bash)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Echo {
  public static void main (String[] args) {
    for (String s: args) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
  }
}
```

You can pass arguments into your main function.  If you are starting jetty from your own application, you would access the args before starting the server.

```
public class SimplestServer
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    Server server = new Server(8080);
    server.start();
    server.join();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. A do this in two threads 1 - start server, 2-parse agrs